# Pandas compare Object columns

Tags: python, pandas, compare

I have two Object columns that contain a list of numbers that I create on panda from 2 CSV files.
I want to compare between two of them and add a new column that will give me the number of identical numbers.

For example:
Table 1:
[Numbers to compare](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUgoN.png)

Table 2:
[Data numbers according to date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zxOL.png)

What I actually interested in is this actual comparison of any number from Table 1 per date in Table 2.

[The desired result, adding a column, which indicates how many numbers exist in the table of the given number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uosSJ.png)

Thank you very much

Comment: Please post the code to reproduce these tables instead of posting images

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

table1:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3, 'd':4
}, index=range(1))
```

table2:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'a':[1, 2, 2, 2], 
    'b':[2, 4, 3, 1],
    'c':[3, 5, 6, 3], 
    'd':[4, 7, 7, 5],
}, index=['01/01/2021', '02/01/2021', '03/02/2021', '04/02/2021'])
```

desired result:

```
df2['no of numbers'] = [
    list(row.isin(df1.values[0])).count(True) \
    for index, row in df2.iterrows()
]
```

it should work.